# Put text on the image in center of it and move it a bit in some direction - ImageMagick

Tags: geometry, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I am challenging again with ImageMagick.

I am trying with following command put text on image (in center location) and later move it -left and right. Documentation says, that gravity can be using in concert with geometry - but it seems not working as I expected. I am trying this command:

```
convert render/pre.button.png -gravity south  -geometry +30+30   -annotate 0 'Faerie Dragon' render/button.png
```

Unfortunately geometry does not work with gravity, for me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these two commands, they should give you two different results:

```
convert \
   in.png \
  -gravity south \
  -annotate 0x0+0+0 'Faerie Dragon' \
   out-1.png

convert \
   in.png \
  -gravity south \
  -annotate 0x0+30+30 'Faerie Dragon' \
   out-2.png
```

The output of the second one is probably similar to the one you intended.